# UNION Results from same SQL each with Different Parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, prepared-statement

I have SQL that pulls data for a given timeframe.  I want to run the SQL multiple times and merge/union the results together into one result set.  Currently I copy the SQL and change the date ranges. As an example:

```
SELECT '2022' AS Period, Name, Status, Wage
  FROM Wages_Table
  WHERE YEAR(Wage_Date) = 2022
UNION
SELECT '2021' AS Period, Name, Status, Wage
  FROM Wages_Table
  WHERE YEAR(Wage_Date) = 2021
UNION
SELECT '2020' AS Period, Name, Status, Wage
  FROM Wages_Table
  WHERE YEAR(Wage_Date) = 2020;
```

Since I need to repeat this for multiple years, I would like to make the year a parameter and execute the SQL repeatedly for each of the years and have all the runs merged together into one results set.

Comment: FYI, you would want a `UNION ALL` if you were to use `UNION` because it performs much better due to straight `UNION` deduplicating results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it as a single query? No need to `UNION` based on what you have shown.

```
DECLARE @StartYear int = 2020;

SELECT YEAR(Wage_Date) AS [Period], [Name], [Status], Wage
FROM Wages_Table
WHERE YEAR(Wage_Date) >= @StartYear
ORDER BY YEAR(Wage_Date) DESC;
```

Comment: `DECLARE @StartDate date = '20200101;` `WHERE Wage_Date >= @StartYear`

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion.  It seems I over simplified my example.  It may be better if I restate the situation.  I'm new to this site and don't know if it's more appropriate to do another question or continue with this thread...  I'll opt for another question...   --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807893/executing-the-same-sql-with-different-parameter-values-but-have-each-result-merg

Comment: Dale K. & Charlieface - I appreciate your assistance. I now see where my question was not detailed to illustrate my situation.  I would appreciate you input on my second attempt to express my challenge --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73807893/executing-the-same-sql-with-different-parameter-values-but-have-each-result-merg